# Delete/Remove Azure AlertRule

Tags: azure, powershell, alert, rules

Remove Command for Azure Alert Rule doesn't seem to work, tried the below it return status no content and the alert is not getting deleted

Command used  **Remove-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroup "RGName" -Name "AlertRuleName"**

[image]

Is there any powershell command which is general for removal of all type of alertrules in azure??

Answer (score 3):

The `Remove-AzAlertRule` command just removes the classic alert rule, its resource type is `microsoft.insights/alertrules`.

[image]

You need to use this command **Remove-AzMetricAlertRuleV2** (description provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-3.7.0)) to remove the non-classic metric alert rule `microsoft.insights/metricAlerts` (the one which are created through the portal).

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer. Forgot about `Remove-AzMetricAlertRuleV2`.

Comment: Thanks,but i have many types of alert not just metric alet, this seems to be specific to metric alert, any generalized command is there for all alert type?

Comment: @Priya.D Well then i guess you will need to write a PowerShell script using remove commands for each alert type based on the resource type.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the alert resource directly with [`Remove-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azresource?view=azps-3.7.0). For demo purposes I am deleting a *metric* alert, which is seen in the resource type `microsoft.insights/metricAlerts`.

```
Remove-AzResource `
    -ResourceGroupName "Resource Group Name" `
    -ResourceName "Alert Name" `
    -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts
```

Which will return `True` if the alert was deleted.

Comment: I have many types of alert, wanted to delete by its name without passing types as using script i need to remove many alertrule

Comment: @Priya.D I don't think there is a general command to remove any type of alert rule. You can run `Get-Command -Name *Alert*` to find all the alert commands. You could just pass the alert types to a script as well. What types of alert rules are you dealing with?

Comment: scheduledQueryRules,activityLogAlerts and also metric alert